# Text on phone smaller than on laptop

Tags: css, responsive-design

The menu on my site are different on my phone and responsive view in Firefox. In the responsive view on my computer with the view-port shrunken to active the responsive design the sizes of fonts and other items are correct. On my phone the menu is tiny.

How it looks on my computer which is correctly shown.

[image: Screenshot of website from computer]

How it looks on my phone.

[image]

My CSS

```
#topMenu{
    background: var(--default-background);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1rem;
    padding-right: 3vw;
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index: 20;
    height: var(--top-menu-height);

}
#topMenu #name{
    font-size: xx-large;
}
```

Following CSS is also running when the viewports are smaller than 1200px wide

```
#topMenu{
    background: rgb(252, 231, 194);
    height: auto;
    padding: 1em;
}
#topMenu #name{
    font-size: xx-large;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a viewport meta tag? Also, can you add some HTML and turn this into an example snippet (SO provides its own snippets while editing your post)?

Comment: I forgo about the viewport meta tag. Adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` solved the problem.

Comment: Nice! I won't post that as an answer, it seems kind of... stupid to elevate my comment into an answer. Glad it helped!

Answer (score -1):

CSS does not have `xx-large` as measurement. Than it's ignored and falling back to default browser font size. Usually on web it's 16px, but on mobile it may be smaller.

Try this:

```
#topMenu #name {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

---

*Side note* [var()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) is not supported in IE.

Comment: xx-large does exists as font-size. I also have tried with 2rem and other sizes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size